# googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled works only when launched from the phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I've added the line `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`
in my code.

When I launch the app from the phone, the map and the location of the user is displayed and everything works well.

However when I launch it from the computer, I get an error :

`08-28 11:19:01.524: W/dalvikvm(30617): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-28 11:19:01.524: D/dalvikvm(30617): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
08-28 11:19:01.529: W/dalvikvm(30617): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-28 11:19:01.529: D/dalvikvm(30617): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
08-28 11:19:02.129: I/dalvikvm(30617): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
08-28 11:19:02.129: W/dalvikvm(30617): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
08-28 11:19:02.129: E/dalvikvm(30617): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
08-28 11:19:02.134: W/dalvikvm(30617): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;`

It seems not to find the Class ParcelableGeofence.
Why ?

In both case a request to the google API is made. So the API key is ok.

If I remove `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` from the code everything works well.

**EDIT** :

1. My full code

   public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   ```
   private GoogleMap googleMap;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.xml.map_layout);

       // Loading map
         initilizeMap();   
   }

   /**
    * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
    * */
   private void initilizeMap() {
       if (googleMap == null) {
           googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                   R.id.map)).getMap();
           googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

           googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

           // check if map is created successfully or not
           if (googleMap == null) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       initilizeMap();
   }}
   ```
2. My XML file

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/></RelativeLayout>`
3. part of my Manifest file

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true"/>

       <permission android:name="packageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />

   <compatible-screens>
       <!-- all small size screens -->
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
       <!-- all normal size screens -->
       <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
       <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
   </compatible-screens>


       <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>



   <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
   </application>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

If this doesn't work, please post your code,manifest,layout xml

Comment: Use FragmentActivity for your class insted of Activity

Comment: Also you are missing permissions:
 <permission
        android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but what happens when you enable the location layer only when the map has loaded? Like this:

```
googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Does the map load properly and then crash?

Comment: The same error occurs. However the map load properly, and then the app crashes.
Again, if I close Eclipse, then it works (I can see the blue dot representing the user). it's very strange ...

Answer (score -1):

Problem is computer doest have GPS or any other way to track location

Comment: I don't launch the app on the simulator, I am launching the app from the computer on the phone